# Track content and simulate key press

Tags: windows, bash, shell, batch-file

I would like to know if it would be too hard to implement the routine below with *.bat file on Windows:

1) detects when an input/textarea (on a Chrome browser) contains a certain word (like "word123")
2) fires a custom physical keypress on the keyboard so the key pressed gets displayed in the input/textarea where the caret is positioned.

This is a very specific use case in a hospital system where we need to detect some special words in medical record where doctors are typing in any page they are browsing.

Comment: Your question is off topic for Stackoverflow, here we help you with issues with your supplied code and you haven't supplied any. You could consider asking your question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Yes, it would be too hard.  HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion is to use something like [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/), which can certainly do the monitoring and simulate a physical key press.  However, if you're triggering based on the word being entered, then the physical key press would happen right away (as soon as the '3' is released in your example).  Agree that this isn't really a programming question yet - if you give AutoHotKey a try and run into issues, come back and post some code.